# Set php value if link is clicked

Tags: php, mysql

I have a own written php forum. On my index page there are three categories, lets say 1-2-3. When you click one of them a file opens.

Respectively cat1.php, 2 and 3 which array all the topics with `catid`= 1, 2 or 3. When you post a topic, the script executes sql query with the details, but how to make the field catid to be with value from the selected category?

Comment: Show us some code. What have you tried?

Comment: Lets say if(category 1 is selected)
{
$catid=1;
} something like that.

Comment: Take it easy on the downvotes people, at least leave a comment. As you can see the OP is new (1 reputation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are asking, but here are some ideas:

Pass it in the URL to your script, like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="cat2.php?catid=2">
   <input type="text" name="topic" value="Enter your topic"/>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In `cat2.php`:

```
$category = $_GET['catid'];
echo "The category is ".$cat;
```

Or, you can save it a session. On top of `cat2.php` (and `cat3.php`, etc.), add this:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['category'] = 2;
?>
```

Now, whenever you want to know the category, simply make sure your PHP file has `session_start();` at the top, and then just `echo $_SESSION['category'];`

You can also pass it in any link, like this:

`<a href="cat2.php?cat=1">This is category one</a>`

Then in your file:

`echo "The category you selected is ". $_GET['cat'];`

Comment: I did that but with multiple files like - addtopic1 for cat1, 2 for 2 etc. But im trying to find a way for doing it with 1 file which is my main problem.

Comment: Just have one file, called `addtopic.php`, and then pass the category id to it as I described in the answer. So all your links will be `addtopic.php?cat=1` if you want to add to category 1, etc.

Comment: It worked. Thank you my friend for the replay, you saved hours of thinking. To all downvoters, have a nice life perfect guys, all the best!